# PHP beginner - what is the function parameter = ""

Tags: php

In the below code I don't know why he put  `= ""` after variable argument.

What is that meaning?

```
function getTextarea($idobj, $nameobj, $valobj="", $width="", $height="", $disabled="" ,$class="InputBox")
{
$idobj = (!$idobj) ? "$nameobj" : "$idobj";
            $height = (!$height) ? "4" : "$height";
            $width = (!$width) ? "30" : "$width";
            return "<textarea id = \"$idobj\" name = \"$nameobj\" cols = \"$width\" rows = \"$height\" class=\"$class\" $disabled >$valobj</textarea>";
}
```

Comment: It is a default value definition for optional arguments.

Comment: I suggest you start reading the official documentation. That will save you a lot of time, answer many questions and suggest a lot of additional ideas to you.

Answer (score 2):

You can make arguments optional by specifying a default value for them. This is explained in the [official PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.default).

> #### Default argument values
>
> A function may define C++-style default values for scalar arguments as follows:
>
> **Example #3 Use of default parameters in functions**
>
> ```
> <?php
> function makecoffee($type = "cappuccino")
> {
>     return "Making a cup of $type.\n";
> }
> echo makecoffee();
> echo makecoffee(null);
> echo makecoffee("espresso");
> ?>
> ```
>
> The above example will output:
>
> ```
> Making a cup of cappuccino.
> Making a cup of .
> Making a cup of espresso.
> ```

Answer (score 1):

it's defining by default (if that parameter is not passed when calling function, here's an example

```
function abc($a = "something"){
 return $a;
}

echo abc(); //something
echo abc("passed"); //passed
```

you can read out more about this [Here [PHP.net]](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php)

Answer (score 1):

This defines the default values of those arguments.

As per PHP manual:

> A function may define C++-style default values for scalar arguments as
>   follows:
>
> Example #3 Use of default parameters in functions

```
<?php
function makecoffee($type = "cappuccino")
{
    return "Making a cup of $type.\n";
}
echo makecoffee();
echo makecoffee(null);
echo makecoffee("espresso");
?>
```

> The above example will output:
>
> Making a cup of cappuccino. Making a cup of . Making a cup of
>   espresso.

Comment: Though it's a valid answer, link answer's are strongly not advised in the event the link ever goes down somebody else wouldn't be able to read said answer.

Comment: Thanks, I edited the answer and will post this way in the future.

Answer (score 1):

They are the default values when the parameters are omitted.

```
function MyParameters($mandatory, $optional1 = 0, $optional2 = "")
```

You can call that function in these ways:

```
MyParameters($someVar);           // $optional1 has value 0, $optional2 has value ""
MyParameters("blah");             // $optional1 has value 0, $optional2 has value ""
MyParameters("blah", 25);         // $optional1 has value 25, $optional2 has value ""
MyParameters("blah", 25, "SsJ");  // $optional1 has value 25, $optional2 has value "SsJ"
```